# How to manage Accord.video.ffmpeg frame setting for real time output

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ffmpeg, accord.net

I am using `accord` for recoding desktop but i have an issue in making video.
when video creates I will become to fast or too slow.

Here is the code:

```
VideoFileWriter writer;
writer.Open(path + "\\video.mp4", re.Width - 6, re.Height - 6, 9, VideoCodec.H264, 15000);
```

I want to make it as real-time like if I made video of 5 minutes then it will show 5 minutes in the player.

Comment: Have you tried to take a look at the ScreenCapture sample application? It might accomplish more or less what you are asking.

Comment: I have solved the problem . I am using ffmpeg now. Thanks